# Integration of $x^2 \sin(x)$ by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I integrate the following?

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\sin(x)\,dx$$

I did $u=x^2$ and $dv=\sin(x)$

I got

$x^2-\cos(x)+2\int x\cos(x)\,dx.\quad$ I then used $u=x$ and $dv=\cos(x).$

I got

$$x^2-\cos(x)+2[x-\sin(x)-\int\sin(x)]$$

then

$x^2-\cos(x)+-2 \sin(x)(x)-\cos(x)\Big|_0^{\pi/2} =\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}-0-2$

Comment: Ok, I thought that this was an auto-answered question.

Comment: @Fernando Martinez consider changing the titles of your last 3 question to something more concrete, such as How to integrate $x^2\sin(x)$ by part. This helps future users who could have the same question

Comment: How would I change the title is in the edit button?

Comment: yes, in Edit you can change your titles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *multiply* $u$ and $v$, then subtract the subsequent integral:

So you should have $$\begin{align} \int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\sin(x)\,dx & = -x^2\cos(x)+2\int x\cos(x)\,dx \\ \\ 
& = -x^2 \cos x + 2\Big[x \sin x - \int \sin x\,dx\Big]\\ \\
& = -x^2\cos x + 2x \sin x - (-2\cos x)\\ \\
& = -x^2 \cos x + 2x \sin x + 2\cos x \Big|_0^{2\pi}\end{align}$$

And proceed from there.

Comment: But would not the negative two turn positive because dv=sin(x) and then $v=-\cos(x)$

Comment: Yes, I had a typo...It looked like you were subtracting $\cos x$ from $x^2$, etc.

Comment: @amWhy: You have been on an integration tear today! +1

Answer (score 3):

$u=x^2$ then $du=2xdx$ and $dv=\sin(x)dx$ then $v=-\cos(x)$. So integral becomes 
$=-(x^2\cos(x))+2\int x\cos(x)dx$
integration by parts for $$\int x\cos(x)dx$$ 
$x=u, dx=du$ and $dv=\cos(x)dx, v=\sin(x)$
then
$$=-(x^2\cos(x))-2\int \sin(x)dx+2x\sin(x)$$
the integral of $\sin x$ is $-\cos x$ so we get
$$=2\cos(x)-x^2\cos(x)+2x\sin(x)$$