# How do the equations below follow?

Tags: fourier-series

$$\int_0^1 x^2\sin(m\pi x)\,dx =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(B_n\int_0^1 \sin(n\pi x) \sin(m\pi x) \, dx\right) , m,n\in \mathbb N  $$

From here how do the equations below follow?
$$\int_0^1 x^2 \sin(n\pi x) \, dx ={1\over 2} B_n $$

$$ B_n=2 {-2+(-1)^n (2-n^2 \pi ^2) \over n^3 \pi ^3 }  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question as it is seems a bit oddly framed to me, so I will start from where I feel is the most natural point to motivate the question. If you want to skip this, then start from the bolded line.

---

We want to find the Fourier series for the function $x^2$; since we are only interested in the function on $(0,1)$, we can choose a series that will involve *sine* terms only (so that the series, when not restricted to $(0,1)$ will actually give the odd periodic extension of $x^2$). We may write*:

$$x^2 = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} B_m \, sin(m \pi x)$$

<sup>*We assume that we are given that such a series representation exists.</sup>

We want to isolate the $n^{th}$ coefficient, $B_n$, and do so by first multiplying each side by $sin(n \pi x)$, and then integrating each side over $[0,1]$:

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^2\sin(n \pi x)\,dx &=\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty B_m\sin(m\pi x) \sin(n\pi x) \, dx\right)\\ \tag{1}
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(B_m\int_0^1 \sin(n\pi x) \sin(m\pi x) \, dx\right)
\end{align}

<sup>We assume here that the order of integration and summation can be interchanged (in fact it can since the Fourier series converges uniformly).</sup>

**This brings us to the entry point of the question**. We now observe the following identities, often referred to as the "*[orthogonality relations](http://www.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/ttu/s10/m3351_s10/sincos_ints_fs.pdf)*" when dealing with Fourier series:

$$ \int_{-1}^1 sin(m \pi x) \, sin(n \pi x) \, dx = \delta_{m n} $$

where $\delta_{m n}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

Noting that the integrand in the above equality is even (since the two *sine* terms are odd, and the product of two odd functions is even), we get

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 sin(m \pi x) \, sin(n \pi x) \, dx &= \frac12 \int_{-1}^1 sin(m \pi x) sin(n \pi x)\, dx\\ \tag{2}
&= \frac{\delta_{m n}}{2}
\end{align}

Now, observe that, by substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$, we can massively simplify equation $(1)$, and isolate the $n^{th}$ coefficient:

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^2 \sin(n\pi x) \, dx &= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} B_m \, \frac{\delta_{m n}}{2}\\
&= \frac12 B_n
\end{align}

But we know how to evaluate the LHS explicitly - for example, we could use integration by parts twice (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486062/integration-of-x2-sinx-by-parts)). Indeed, this gives,

$$ \text{LHS}= {-2+(-1)^n (2-n^2 \pi ^2) \over n^3 \pi ^3 }  $$

as required.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. So what about this part: $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} B_m \frac{\delta_{m n}}{2}=\frac12 B_n $

Comment: @LeylaAlkan Happy to help... I'm not sure I understand your question though - I will try however: We have fixed $n$ - this is just some number. $\delta_{m n}$ is equal to zero when $m \ne n$ and is $1$ when $m = n$. Therefore, in the sum, all of the terms $B_m \cdot \delta_{m n}$ will be equal to zero for $m \ne n$, leaving just the $n^{th}$ term. Perhaps this is better: $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} B_m \cdot \delta_{m n}$$ $$=(B_1 \cdot \delta_{1, n}) + (B_2 \cdot \delta_{2, n}) + ... + (B_n \cdot \delta_{n, n}) + ...$$ $$= (B_1 \cdot 0) + (B_2 \cdot 0) + ... (B_n \cdot 1) + ...$$ $$= B_n$$

Comment: That is what I exactly wanted to be answered. I really appreciated! @JohnDon

Comment: For even functions wouldn't one use the cosine series? (The given series would be good for an odd extension of $x^2$, with issues of discontinuity at end point)

Comment: @Maesumi You are absolutely correct - I have added the small point needed to rectify this in the answer (essentially, since we only care about $x^2$ in $(0,1)$, we may choose an odd extension of it to $(-1, 1)$. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @Maesumi You are also correct about the issue of continuity at the end-point; in this case, it is not something we need to consider, as we are looking at an integral over $[0,1]$, so the value at $\\{1\\}$ (a set of measure 0) will have no effect.